# Socket verification from ServerSocket Java

Tags: java, sockets

i'm trying create "multi-client -- single server" connection.
My client(s) opens connection and in the server side I've create

```
     Client clt = new Client("127.0.0.1", 9000);
        clt.openConn();

...

public Client(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
    this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    this.serverPort = serverPort;
}
try {
        this.clientSocket = new Socket(this.serverAddress, this.serverPort);
        this.clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
        this.clientSocket.setSoTimeout(0);

            oos = new DataOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            ois = new DataInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());...}
```

...

on the server side i've created ListArray of ServerSocket's each onf them I wrapped on the Thread.

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null ;
        Socket clientSocket;
        boolean listening = true;
        ArrayList threadList = new ArrayList();
        Iterator itSrvThr;
    try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port + ".");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        while (listening) {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ServerThread srvThread = new ServerThread(clientSocket);
            srvThread.start();
`...`
    }
```

where

```
 ServerThread extends Thread
    {...
         public void run() {
           this.ois = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
           this.oos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());    
         }
    }
```

my program send and receive objects(i've called them "Datagramm") which are some kind of wrappers for file and strings (let us say it is some language for client-server)

And now about problem which I have. I must to make verification every time when need to test for "alive" socket from server side...
i'm trying to make this verification when appears new element in the ArrayList in that moment but it brings me problem with "Datagramm's" sending

```
itSrvThr = threadList.iterator();
            while (itSrvThr.hasNext()) {
                ServerThread st = (ServerThread) itSrvThr.next();
                boolean stoppedSocket = st.getStopped();

                if (stoppedSocket) {
                    st.stop();
                    itSrvThr.remove();
                }else {??? resolution???}
```

stoppedSocket - it's a value which significate programly turned off socket from client site.

Honestly, i'm working with sockets and threads only a couple weeks, that is why every help and critics will be acceptable.
...
Thank for answer but I have problems with codding of heartbeats. First of them where exactly the place of heartbeat must be placed on the server side.

Comment: What's the *question?* You seem to be asking what to do if the socket isn't 'stopped'. That's the normal case - you just keep using it. The hard case is deciding when it *is* 'stopped'. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you send a heartbeat message from the client and/or the server whenever you haven't sent a message for a while (seconds) The other end can timeout when you haven't recieved anything for some multiple of this time.

If you have a protocol like {message length} {message} I use a message-length=0 as a heartbeat.